# broadcast messages to all connected clients in Django websockets

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

a have a Django chat application using web sockets and channels,the wecbokect connection is establish as you can see here:

```
[mansard@web569 src]$ python3.5 manage.py runserver 22783 Performing system checks...
Django version 1.11, using settings 'chatbot.settings'
2017-09-04 16:53:05,478 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-04 16:53:05,479 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-04 16:53:05,479 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-09-04 16:53:05,480 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2017-09-04 16:53:05,480 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
2017-09-04 16:53:05,480 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint tcp:port=22783:interface=127.0.0.1
[2017/09/04 16:54:09] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /webscok/ [127.0.0.1:42846]
[2017/09/04 16:54:09] WebSocket CONNECT /webscok/ [127.0.0.1:42846]
```

**chat.js:**

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    $messages.mCustomScrollbar();
   var ws_path = "/webscok/";
   var socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + ws_path);
   socket.onmessage = function(e) {chatMessage(e.data);}
   $('.message-submit').click(function() {
                                      msg = $('.message-input').val();
                                      socket.send(msg);
                                      insertMessage(msg);});
   $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
                                      if (e.which == 13) {
                                          msg = $('.message-input').val();
                                          socket.send(msg);
                                          insertMessage(msg);}});
  setTimeout(function() {
      welcomingMessage();}, 100);
});
```

**consumers.py:**

```
import json
from channels import Channel , Group
from channels.auth import http_session_user, channel_session_user, channel_session_user_from_http
from channels.sessions import channel_session

def ws_connect(message):
     message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
     Group('chat').add(message.reply_channel)
def ws_receive(message):
    Group('chat').send({"text": message.content['text'],})
def ws_disconnect(message):
   Group('chat').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

**routing.py:**

```
from channels.routing import route
from Pchat.consumers import ws_connect, ws_disconnect, ws_receive

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect,path=r"^/webscok"),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
]
```

**settings.py:**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer", 
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": ['unix:///home/mansard/webapps/gadgetron/var/redis.sock',],},
        "ROUTING": "chatbot.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

**cht.html:**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>المساعد الذكي</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css'>
  <link rel="icon" href="/static/icon.png">
  <link rel="favicon.ico" href="/static/icon.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/chatbot_style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="chat-title">
    <h1>محمد .. online now</h1>
    <h2>الـمـسـاعـد الـذكـي</h2>
    <figure class="avatar">
      <img src="/static/icon.png" /></figure>
  </div>
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="messages-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-box">
    <textarea type="text" class="message-input" placeholder="اكتب سؤالك هنا"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="message-submit">ارسال</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="bg"></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.3/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js'></script>
<script src="/static/js/channels/js/websocketbridge.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/PP_chat_index.js"></script>
```

i tried echoing the messages back to me and  it work perfectly. Now i moved on creating a chat server that adds a new client to the chat group and broadcast any incoming messages to all connected clients , i have configure and installed everything but the Group() doesn't work and nothing is happing and no error have been shown so i don't know where is the problem?